# Formula for $M_{p^k} = \{ x \in \Bbb{Z} : x^2 = 1 \pmod {p^k}\}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, integers, monoid

Let $M_n = \{ x \in \Bbb{Z}: x^2 = 1 \pmod n\}$.  It is a multiplicative submonoid of $\Bbb{Z}$.

When $\gcd(a,b) = 1$ then we have:

$$
x^2 = 1\pmod {a,b} \iff \\
x^2 = 1\pmod {ab}
$$

by the Chinese remainder theorem, which means $M_{ab} = M_a \cap M_b$.

My question is, do we have a formula for $M_{p^k}$ where $p^k$ is the $k$th power of a prime $p$?

What is known: if $n \mid m$ then $M_m \subset M_n$.  So we have that $M_{p^k} \subset M_{p^{k-1}}$ for all $k \geq 2$.

For $p \gt 2$ we can't have both $x-1, x+1 \in (p)$ so if $x^2 - 1 \in (p^k)$ it's true that either $x-1 \in (p^k)$ or $x + 1 \in (p^k)$ but not both.

Comment: you are correct, and, if $x^2\equiv1\bmod p^k$, then $x\equiv\pm1\bmod p^k$

Comment: For $p$  odd since $2$ is coprime with $p^{k-1}$ and $\{ z \bmod p^k, z=1\bmod p\}$ is a group with $p^{k-1}$ elements, if $y^2= 1 \bmod p$ then $y^{2 p^{k-1}} = 1\bmod p^k$ and every square root of $1$ is of this form $x=y^{p^{k-1}},y^2=1\bmod p$, which means there are 2 square roots $\bmod p^k$. When $p=2,k\ge 3$ there are 4 square roots.

Comment: @reuns can you go into detail in an answer?

Comment: I'm wanting to expression $M_n$ in a general formula

Comment: Try a detailed proof of my claims and tell us where you are stuck (for $p$ even look at the group $\{ z\bmod 2^k, z= 1\bmod 4\}$, it is cyclic generated by $5$ because $(1+4)^{2^m} = 1+2^{m+2}\bmod 2^{m+3}$)

Comment: @reuns okay I will work on it! Thx

Comment: @reuns I'm having trouble seeing that $\{z \pmod p^k : z = 1 \pmod p\}$ is a group with $p^{k-1}$ elements, namely the cardinality.

Comment: @reuns how does this apply back to the monoid situation?

Comment: @ShineOnYouCrazyDiamond this the kernel of the surjective reduction map $$(\mathbf Z/p^k \mathbf Z)^\times \rightarrow (\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z)^\times$$ so it has $\phi(p^k)/\phi(p) = p^{k-1}$ elements.

Comment: It is obvious it is a group and it is obvious its elements are $1+ bp, b\in 0\ldots p^{k-1}-1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hensel's lemma states that for any polynomial function $f(x)$, in this case $f(x) = x^2 - 1$, if it has a simple root over $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ for prime $p$, then there is a unique corresponding root over $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$, which can be found by iteratively using [Hensel lifting](https://www.cmi.ac.in/~ramprasad/lecturenotes/comp_numb_theory/lecture26.pdf) from $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.